# Save TinyMCE in MySQL and retrieve with style

Tags: php, mysql

I have manage to integrate TinyMCE and connecting it with mysql. Now I save it into database but there is some problem with some tags. For example when I save `ul`, `li`, `ol` they are saved in database like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ol>
   <li>64</li>
   <li>4</li>
</ol>
<p>4</p>
<p>4</p>
```

But on the page they are displayed like this

```
1
2
3
4
5

64
4
4
4
```

I save them like this

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "somepass", "db");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s<br/>", mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($db, "UTF8");

$query = "INSERT INTO posts (post_text, post_title, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
$conn = $db->prepare($query);
if ($conn == TRUE) {
    $conn->bind_param("ssi",$text, $title, $category );
    if (!$conn->execute()) {
        echo 'error insert';
    } else {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

And this is how I retrieve and show them on the website

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $post_id");
    foreach ($query as $row) {

    echo '<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
               <div class="portfolio-slider-wrapper">
                    <h4>'.$row['post_title'].'</h4>
                    <hr>                  
                    <p>
                        '.$row['post_text'].'
                    </p>
               </div>
          </div>';
```

So how to show the text like is posted and saved in database?

Answer (score 1):

To display the HTML format output replace

```
<p>
                        '.$row['post_text'].'
                    </p>
```

with the following code.

```
<p>'.echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['post_text'])).'</p>
```

Comment: Try `htmlentities(stripslashes($row['post_text']));`